# php URL rewrite wamp

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I want to implement URL rewrite in wamp.
My ugly link is:
http://mysite.com/news.php?id=4654654&title=asdasdasdas-das-dasd-as-da-sda-d-asd-ads-as-da-sd
I want pretty URL to be 
http://mysite.com/4654654/asdasdasdas-das-dasd-as-da-sda-d-asd-ads-as-da-sd

Using online generator on www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/ for my link I get this .htaccess result:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /news.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

in wamp apache rewrite_module is checked, in httpd.conf I change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. I removed # sign from  `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

But when I click on hred with link like this http://mysite.com/4654654/asdasdasdas-das-dasd-as-da-sda-d-asd-ads-as-da-sd , I receive Not Found error `The requested URL /myfolder/4654654/asdasdasdas-das-dasd-as-da-sda-d-asd-ads-as-da-sd was not found on this server`

site root folder is in c:/www/myfolder

Can someone tell me what should I do to work this?

Thanks

---

EDIT

should I made some changes in my php file except href values?

Answer (score 0):

create a new `.htaccess` file in your web root directory i.e `c:/www/myfolder` and place the code in it. and it should work.

Comment: did you restart your apache server after making changes?

Answer (score 0):

The RewriteRule-part should start in a new line under RewriteEngine on.

There is a good beginner's guide with explanations at:
http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite